# How do I remove button formating in a form so the buttons are used as toggle buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jsp

I built a checkout page and there's a form to get user data.

The form goes like this:

```
<form method="post" action="purchase" name="checkout"></form
```

When user clicks on `"confirm order"`, they are being directed to the `confirmation.jsp` as supposed.

Inside of that form I added buttons to be used as toggling effect to hide and show a given section of the form.

The problem:

- When I click on > + < the given section shows and when I click on > - < the given section hides but then the `confirmation.jsp page` loads up as if the buttons acted as link to that page, just like the `"confirmation order button"`. I tried to add normal buttons, same event happens. Every button put on that form seems to automatically be formatted to act as a "confirm order button", no matter what I try.

The buttons go like this:

```
<button id="show" class="toggle_button" value=$("#show").click action=$("#show").click >+</button>
<button id="hide" class="toggle_button" value=$("#hide").click action=$("#hide").click>-</button>
```

And the scripts in the header:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#hide").click(function(){
            $("p").hide();
        });
        $("#show").click(function(){
            $("p").show();
        });
    });
    </script>
        </head>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What that suppesed to be: `value=$("#show").click action=$("#show").click` ? It's not valid markup.

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` should work for you - http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
<input type="button" id="show" class="toggle_button" onclick="doAction('show')" value="+" />
<input type="button" id="hide" class="toggle_button" onclick="doAction('hide')" value="-" />

<script>
    $("#show").click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    });
    $("#hide").click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    function doAction(action) {
       if(action=="hide") {
           $("p").hide();
       } else {
          $("p").show();    
       }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Mucho thanks amigo! Tried it just now and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

The default type for a button in a form is type="submit". 
Try to add 'type="button"' on each of them.

```
<button type="button" id="show" class="toggle_button" value=$("#show").click action=$("#show").click >+</button>
<button type="button" id="hide" class="toggle_button" value=$("#hide").click action=$("#hide").click>-</button>
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
.btn {
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 60px;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<button id="show" class="toggle_button btn" value=$("#show").click action=$("#show").click >+</button>
<button id="hide" class="toggle_button btn" value=$("#hide").click action=$("#hide").click>-</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you put a button in a form it's default `type` is `submit` unless you explicitly set it to `button`.

You are therefore submitting the form unintentionally

Change to

```
 <button type="button"></button>
```

Alternatively in javascript you can also use `event.preventDefault()` within click handlers